# Is there any in-memory option for temporal server so that we can test it with embedded kafka and spring boot test?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-boot-test, temporal-workflow

I am creating a spring boot application using Temporal as a workflow engine and kafka topics .
So in order to validate whole setup is working fine, I am writing integration test cases using spring boot test, embedded kafka, and temporal. But I am not getting any option or way to run in memory workflow engine.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this distribution of Temporal that runs as a single process
https://github.com/DataDog/temporalite